# How do I get the type of one side of a union object?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I was tring to discern the type of a value returned by a 3rd party library. Unfortunately the type was the left hand side of a non-discriminated union, and was anonymous (i.e. not labeled).

See example below:

```js
// given an anonymous return type from a non-discriminated union...
const someFn = function(): ({ colour: string, flavour: string } | Error) {
    return { colour: 'blue', flavour: 'blue' }
}

// how do I extract the left hand side type?
type Flavour = FlavourOrError[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

(TIL) I was able to discern the type, by using the `ReturnType` from the function.

And then using `Extract` to get the left hand side type.

If anyone knows a better way of doing this, please let me know!

```js
// 1. get the return type of the function...
type ReturnUnion = ReturnType<typeof someFn>

// 2. extract the left hand side type, using a sample field...
type LeftHandSideType = Extract<ReturnUnion, { colour: string }>

// 3. later, use duck typing...
const value = someFn()
if (typeof (value as LeftHandSideType).colour !== 'undefined') {
    // do something with it...
}
```

Comment: You could also just check if the returned value was an error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't use the "regular JavaScript" way and check if the returned value was an error:

```
const value = someFn();

if (!(value instanceof Error)) {
    // do something with it...
}
```

This works just as well, without using `ReturnType` and `Extract`. However, if the return type of `someFn` is more complicated in your real code, then it might be more desirable to use `ReturnType` with `Extract`.